# Java NIO invalid path issue; illegal <:>, caused by an invalid preceding character

Tags: java, sqlite, nio, illegal-characters

I'm trying to upload an image file to a sqlite database via it's file-path using the code below

```
// Upload image to table //
            byte[] bytesFromFile = null;
            try {
                String fileName = imageField.getText();
                File f = new File(fileName);
                bytesFromFile = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            stmt.setBytes (12,  bytesFromFile);
```

When executed, I end up with this error

`java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: 
Illegal char <:> at index 2: ?C:\Users\SAMUE\Downloads\BigWindow.jpg`

What I find very strange is I could have absolutely sworn when I tested this two days ago it worked fine, but maybe I'm just losing my mind.

I've tried implementing the other solutions for similar problems on here (converting to uri, etc.) but they are either not working or I just don't know how to implement them in the way I need to.

I don't know if this is useful information but for all the similar problems it seemed a leading '\' character was the culprit, but as you can see I'm getting that question-mark placed at the beginning of the file-path, I'm guessing that that may be a source of the issue, or that may just be an eclipse thing.

**EDIT**:

Hello, so sorry to waste your time, I have found the solution, it seems getting the path from the TextField appended that "?", I merely took the substring after it and it works fine now. I'm leaving this up in hopes that anyone that has a similar issue can be helped. If you think this is better off deleted, let me know.

Comment: Hmm, the title does not really match the resolved problem

Comment: My guess is it was something similar to the other issues where the leading '\' was causing that same error; that is the error message that would come up for those questions. Mine was the same issue, but in somewhat of a different form- how it seems to me at least